# Multiple "relays" in NGINX - is it possible?

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to configure NGINX to something like multiple reverse-proxy? So, instead of one `proxy_pass`:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

to have multiple `proxy_pass`s (relays)? I need something like load balancer but to send not to one of them, but TO ALL (see the scheme below).

TO BE ACCURATE: IT'S NOT REVERSE PROXY AND IT IS NOT LOAD BALANCING AS WELL.

The response may be retrieving from any of them, maybe the last one or even to be "hardcoded" with some configuration directives - it does not matter (it's enough to be HTTP 200 and will be ignored)... So, the scheme should look like:

```
             .----> server 1
            /
<---> NGINX <-----> server 2 (response from 2nd server, but it maybe any of them!)
            \
             `----> server 3
```

Maybe some extension for NGINX? Is it possible at all and how to do it if it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
What you are searching for is called mirroring. And nginx implements it since version 1.13.4, see the directive [mirror](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html) for more info.
Example:

```
  location = /mirror1 {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://mirror1.backend$request_uri;
  }
  location = /mirror2 {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://mirror2.backend$request_uri;
  }
...
  location /some/path/ {
    mirror /mirror1;
    mirror /mirror2;
    proxy_pass http://primary.backend;
  }
```

*(you can also specify it for whole `server` (or even `http`) and disable for locations where you don't need it).*

Alternatively you could try `post_action` (but this is undocumented feature and if I remember correctly is deprecated).